# Why doesn't my PyQt USB serial connection work until after I've connected with another serial monitor?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtserialport, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico connected via USB to a Windows 10 PC running a Python script using PyQt.

I've found that the serial comms (over USB) between my Pico and the Python script on the PC doesn't work. If I open a connection using Arduino's Serial Monitor, or using pyserial, it does work. You'd think this would be a simple case of my use of PyQt's QSerialPort just being wrong, but if I try to connect to the PyQt-based script after having connected to the Serial Monitor, or another Python script that uses pyserial, it works with no issue.

I don't have to have sent anything using the pyserial-based script, just made the connection and ended the program. The same with the Arduino Serial Monitor, just made the connection and then closed the Serial Monitor window. If I reset the Pico by unplugging the USB cable, I have to connect to the Serial Monitor again or run the pyserial script before I can connect to the PyQt script.

I did find [this similar issue in Raspberry Pi forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=188646), but the suggested fix there (10uF capacitor between RESET and GND on an Arduino hasn't helped me. (I didn't expect it would.)

Minimal code to reproduce:

Arduino on the Pico (a standard program I use to test serial comms)

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define ONBOARD_LED_GPIO 25

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1);

  pinMode(ONBOARD_LED_GPIO, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ONBOARD_LED_GPIO, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    digitalWrite(ONBOARD_LED_GPIO, HIGH);
    String test = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    test += ".";
    Serial.print(test);
    digitalWrite(ONBOARD_LED_GPIO, LOW);
  }
}
```

PyQt Python on the PC (stripped down from my code)

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QIODevice, QByteArray
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort, QSerialPortInfo
import sys


class SerialTester(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.show()

        self._serial = QSerialPort(self)
        self._connect_serial()

        self._serial.readyRead.connect(self._read_serial)
        self.testButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.write("test\n"))

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("SerialTester")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.testButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)

    def _connect_serial(self):
        port, ok_pressed = self._get_serial_port_dialog()
        if ok_pressed and port:
            self._serial.setPortName(port)
            if self._serial.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite):
                # Connect success
                self._serial.setBaudRate(115200)
                self._serial.setDataBits(8)
                self._serial.setParity(0)
                self._serial.setStopBits(1)
                return True
        return False
            
    def _get_serial_port_dialog(self):
        ports = [item.portName() for item in QSerialPortInfo.availablePorts()]
        if len(ports) == 0:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            msg.setText("No ports available!")
            msg.setWindowTitle("Connection Error")
            msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
            msg.exec()
            return None, False
        port, ok_pressed = QInputDialog.getItem(
            self,
            "Choose port",
            "Valve Controller Port:",
            ports,
            0,
            False)
        return port, ok_pressed

    def _read_serial(self):
        received_str = self._serial.readAll().data().decode()
        print("Received: " + received_str)

    def write(self, write_str):
        self._serial.write(QByteArray(write_str.encode()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = SerialTester()
    view.show()    

    # Execute event loop, and exit properly when it's finished
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

A working pyserial example

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ser = serial.Serial(
        port="COM11",
        baudrate=115200,
        bytesize=8,
        timeout=1,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
        )
    while True:
        ser.write("test".encode())
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Read: " + ser.readall().decode())
```

Comment: I think you need to call QSerialPortInfo as a function. `QSerialPortInfo().availablePorts()`

Comment: Same issue, but using the C++ version of QtSerialPort. Also I have same behaviour: After opening the port with the arduino's serial monitor, the communication works with QtSerialPort. So this is not a python issue

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue with the information of [Windows COM access to PICO via USB trouble](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=327980).
After you opened the port, call [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtSerialPort/QSerialPort.html#PySide6.QtSerialPort.PySide6.QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.setDataTerminalReady)

```
QSerialPort::setDataTerminalReady(true)
```